# RxJava: Insert list of objects as well as its nested objects

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have a list of "user" entities, I can insert all the users with :

```
Completable.fromAction(() -> userDao.insert(users))
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

This works fine.

However, each user entity has a list of "Address" entities, like this: List.

In the repository I have a AddressDao, I want to chain another completable to insert all the addresses along with the users.

It should look like something like this:

```
Completable.fromAction(() -> userDao.insert(users))
.andThen(Completable.fromAction(() -> addressDao.insert(foreach(user).address))
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

But this does not compile because I don't know the syntax, and I am not sure if I should use andThen. Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

To extract the list of addresses from the list of users, you can use Java 8 stream.

```
List<Address> addresses = users.stream()
    .flatMap(user -> user.address.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Full answer:

```
Completable.fromAction(() -> userDao.insert(users))
    .andThen(Completable.fromAction(() -> {
        addressDao.insert(users.stream()
            .flatMap(user -> user.address.stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

Stream is just there for you to simplify the code. If Stream is not available just simple iteration is also okay.

```
final List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

for (User user: users) {
    for (Address address: user) {
        addresses.add(address);
    }
}
```

Full answer:

```
final List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

for (User user: users) {
    for (Address address: user) {
        addresses.add(address);
    }
}

Completable.fromAction(() -> userDao.insert(users))
    .andThen(Completable.fromAction(() -> addressDao.insert(addresses))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

Comment: Hi, in fact I would like to insert the addresses, not extracting them

Comment: Correct me I am wrong, I thought you were trying to insert addresses into DB. That means you need to extract address instances from the user instances to make a list of addresses.

Comment: Yes I now understand, thank you that's what I want. However, I'm using API 23 so users.stream won't work, do you have an alternative ? Thank you !

Comment: All Java 8 Streams can easily be replaced with Java 7 or lower codes. I will update the answer.